# How to change the display property in a css class using js when user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a webapp that I plan on converting to a smartphone app using Phone Gap Build. I've never done this before so may not be describing my problem clearly but here goes. 
I started using the jquery mobile sample in Dreamweaver, this has multiple pages in a single html file. What I'd like to do is have a series of English phrases on each page, each English phrase will be followed by the formal Spanish translation and then the informal Spanish translation. At the top of the page the user will have three buttons saying "Formal", "Informal" and "Formal & Informal". The user will always see the English phrases followed by the Formal, Informal or Formal & Informal Spanish depending on which buttons they pressed/ tapped.

The home page can be seen here http://www.pslt.biz/mobileApp/LE4/index3.html then click "Age, Weight & Height" and you'll see that clicking the Formal/ Informal buttons has no effect on the Spanish underneath the first phrase "How old are you". 
If it helps here's the Formal button which should set the CSS class ".formal" to Display:Block and the ".informal" class to Display:None

```
     <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('formal').style.display='block';document.getElementById('informal').style.display='none';">Display   Formal</a>
```

The CSS classes are defined externally as follows:

```
    .formal { display:block;
    }

    .informal {display:block;
    }
```

And the Spanish phrases are defined in divs as follows:

```
     <div class="formal"> <!-- Start Formal -->
             <div style="float:left">
                 <a href="#" onclick="playSound('Sounds/testaycaramba.mp3');">
                 <img src="images/audio-75.gif" alt="" width="25" height="25" /></a>
              </div>
              <div style="float:left">
                  Cuántos años tiene?
              </div>
      </div> <!-- End Formal -->
      <div class="informal"> <!-- Start informal -->
              <div style="clear:left">
                  <div  style="float:left">
                      <a href="#" onclick="playSound('Sounds/testaycaramba.mp3');">
                      <img src="images/audio-75.gif" alt="" width="25" height="25" /></a>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                       Cuántos años tienes?
                  </div>
              </div>
      </div> <!-- End informal -->
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it, I thought it would be simple to do but I must be missing something blindingly obvious.

Comment: Do you just need to toggle (show / hide) these divs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery:

```
<a href="#" 
    onclick="$('.formal').css('display', 'block'); $('.informal').css('display', 'none');">Display Formal</a>
```

The problem is your divs have classes "formal" and "informal", not ids and you are selecting by ID.

Another option:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="$('.formal').show();$('.informal').hide()">Display Formal</a>
```

Comment: I used the second option above and it worked using show/ hide and it worked. Thank you so much. next I'll test to see if setting Formal/ Informal will be remembered when I go to a different page, I'm using Jquery Mobile so all pages are in the same physical html page. Ideally I'd like that to work but I think my users can live without that feature. Thanks again to all for your input, I was hitting ab brick wall until you all stepped forward to help, thanks again.

Comment: It remembers what to display when I change pages - that's exactly what I wanted. thank you all so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getElementsByClassName()` instead of `getElementById()`.

**You have selector by class name, not by id** Or replace `class="informal"` and `class="formal"` with `id="informa1"` etc.

Comment: Note: getElementsByClassName() will not work before IE9, just in case anyone is concerned.

Comment: Since he's having jQuery already loaded, he might just as well use the jquery selectors: $('.formal').hide() / show()

Comment: @bouscher your comment should be an answer and should be the accepted one!

Comment: actually he should just use .toggle()

Comment: as for @groonel answer - class shouldn't be replaced with id; there should be an id to be used as the js hook *and* a then the class should be set to formal/informal. keep javascript unobstrusive and avoid id replacement

Comment: @Luca That would make things for him a lot easier, but it's never a bad thing to learn the good old way to do it, i.e. not dive into jquery unless you know about javascript/ECMA.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this first as it seemed closer to what I was trying to do, unfortunately it didn't work, the Formal and Informal both displayed. Here's the code for the buttons

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('formal').style.display='block';document.getElementsByClassName('informal').style.display='none';">Display Formal</a>
           <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('formal').style.display='none';document.getElementsByClassName('informal').style.display='block';">Display Informal</a>
           <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('formal').style.display='block';documen t.getElementsByClassName('informal').style.display='block';">Display Formal & Informal</a>

Comment: Here's a link to the page         http://www.pslt.biz/mobileApp/LE4/index4.html#ageWtHt

Comment: I'm using IE10/ Win 7 if that makes a difference. I'll try one of the other approaches next and report back

Answer (score 1):

The solution from MiFeet worked perfectly. I used 
           Display Formal

For some reason I was unable to show that as the answer, I received an error when I clicked on the checkbox, I hope this helps someone else.

Tony Babb

Comment: Does it really throw an error? That's strange, could you try again?

Answer (score 0):

**JS code:**

```
button.onclick=function(){

    element=document.getElementsByClassName("formal")[0];
    element.className="informal";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have `class="informal"` then replace it with `class="informal1"` and try this

```
<a href="#" onclick="change();" id="remove" class="informal">Display Formal</a>

function change(){

$('#remove').removeClass('informal');
$("#remove").addClass("informal1");

}
```